# C# Winforms DataGridView selected cell is clearing cell value

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, datagridviewrow, datagridviewcellstyle

I'm developing a booking system. I'm using multiple DGVs to visually display booked slots for different rooms based on 30 minute slot cells in a DGV, each room has its own DGV. I used a foreach statement on each room to create a new DGV, change the properties appropriately, add rows for each time slot and if they match a booking time, change the cell color and value before adding it to the DGV and adding the DGV to the form.

The code for this is:

```
public partial class BookingSystem : Form
{
    List<string> RoomList = new List<string>();


    public BookingSystem()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        this.Text = "Booking System - " + DateTime.Today.DayOfWeek.ToString() + " " + DateTime.Today.ToString("dd MMM yyyy");

        RoomList.Add("Community Room 3");
        RoomList.Add("Community Room 2");
        RoomList.Add("Community Room 1");
        RoomList.Add("Sports Hall");
        //RoomList.Add("New Room");

        DateTime bookingStart = DateTime.Parse("23/11/2021 10:30:00");
        DateTime bookingStart2 = DateTime.Parse("23/11/2021 11:00:00");
        DateTime bookingEnd = DateTime.Parse("23/11/2021 11:30:00");

        this.Width = 1080;

        foreach (string room in RoomList)
        {
            DataGridViewCellStyle dgvCellStyle = new DataGridViewCellStyle();
            Color color = Color.FromArgb(255, 224, 224, 224);
            dgvCellStyle.BackColor = color;

            DataGridView roomSchedule = new DataGridView();

            roomSchedule.Dock = DockStyle.Left;
            roomSchedule.Width = 200;
            roomSchedule.Columns.Add(room, room);
            roomSchedule.Columns[0].Width = 135;
            roomSchedule.RowHeadersWidth = 63;
            roomSchedule.AlternatingRowsDefaultCellStyle = dgvCellStyle;
            roomSchedule.RowHeadersBorderStyle = DataGridViewHeaderBorderStyle.Raised;
            roomSchedule.ColumnHeadersBorderStyle = DataGridViewHeaderBorderStyle.Single;
            //roomSchedule.ReadOnly = true;
            roomSchedule.SelectionMode = DataGridViewSelectionMode.RowHeaderSelect;
            roomSchedule.AllowUserToResizeRows = false;

            DateTime openingTime = DateTime.Parse("07:00");
            DateTime closingTime = DateTime.Parse("22:00");
            TimeSpan openingHours = closingTime - openingTime;
            DateTime currentTimeSlot = openingTime;
            double totalRows = openingHours.TotalMinutes / 30;

            int rows = 0;

            while (rows <= totalRows)
            {
                DataGridViewRow row = new DataGridViewRow();

                DataGridViewCellStyle bookedCellStyle = new DataGridViewCellStyle();
                bookedCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Moccasin;
                DataGridViewCell bookedCell = new DataGridViewTextBoxCell();
                bookedCell.Value = "Class Name";
                bookedCell.Style = bookedCellStyle;
                
                row.HeaderCell.Value = currentTimeSlot.ToString("HH:mm");
                roomSchedule.Rows.Add(row);
                
                if (currentTimeSlot.TimeOfDay == bookingStart.TimeOfDay || currentTimeSlot.TimeOfDay == bookingStart2.TimeOfDay)
                {
                    if (room == "Sports Hall")
                    {
                        row.Cells[0] = bookedCell;
                        //row.Cells[0].Value = "Class Name";
                    }
                }

                currentTimeSlot = currentTimeSlot.AddMinutes(30);

                roomSchedule.RowsDefaultCellStyle.SelectionBackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Transparent;
                rows++;
            }
            
            dgvBox.Controls.Add(roomSchedule);
        }    
    }
}
```

However when a value for a cell is entered this way, the value gets cleared when ever the cell is selected.

Disabling the DGVs or making the DGV rows read only would fix this issue but I would like to keep the ability to select cells.

The problem is being created by setting the cell value using DataGridViewCellStyle.Value

```
bookedCell.Value = "Gravity ASD";
```

but I can't find any other way to set the cell value, as using:

```
row.Cells[0].Value = "Class Name";
```

before the row is added to the DGV, gives me this exception message: Specified argument was out of the range of valid values

and if its after the row is added to the DGV it gives me this exception message: Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection

Is there a way to either add the value to the cell another way or a way to stop the selected cell value from being cleared?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears you may be making this more complicated than it has to be. However; I may not understand the requirements. After some small tests, is what stands out as ODD is the way the code is adding the rows to the grid. Starting with…

```
DataGridViewRow row = new DataGridViewRow(); … ? …
```

this is odd and it may work; however, it is unnecessary and it appears to be creating some odd behavior as you describe.

I would think that since you already have the `DataGridView` … `roomSchedule` WITH a column, that you may want to get a “NEW ROW” from “THAT GRID” as opposed to creating a new row from scratch. Something like…

```
int rowIndex = roomSchedule.Rows.Add();
DataGridViewRow row = roomSchedule.Rows[rowIndex];
```

The same idea would apply to the “CELL” in the row. There is no need to “create” a new one since the row we got from the grid already has a cell. I hope that makes sense.

```
DataGridViewCell bookedCell = row.Cells[0];
```

These changes appear to make the grid behave as expected. Sorry if I am missing something and I hope this makes sense.